# Drawing a simple graph with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, graph-drawing

I am looking to do some simple drawing with in a WPF application, I was wondering if this is a simple task or if I should look into some 3rd party libraries.

Quite simply I just want to draw on an image control some points and lines between those points.  Is this something easy to do?

thanks!

Comment: Yes, it can be done with a basic knowledge of shapes provide in System.Windows.Shapes namespace .http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.aspx

Comment: How would one draw that to an image control?

Comment: You can set your image as Background of the container control (Canvas) using ImageBrush and Draw them simply on your Canvas.

Comment: You may as well overlay a Canvas (which is transparent by default) over an Image control. Put both in a Grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a sample to use ..you can draw a line using basics only...

how to set canvas backgroud as image..

```
  ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"sampleImages\berries.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
mycanvas.Background = ib;
```

and you can now draw on your canvas a line like this..

```
line = new Line();
line.Stroke = Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
line.X1 = 1;
line.X2 = 50;
line.Y1 = 1;
line.Y2 = 50;
line.StrokeThickness = 2;
myCanvas.Children.Add(line);
```

hope it will help you to start..

Comment: Quick question, I modified it to be:Image ib = new ImageBrush();
            ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage();
            canvas1.Background = ib;  But I seem t oget an issue: "BitmapImage has not been initialized.  Call the BeginInit method, set the appropriate properties, and then call the EndInit method."

Comment: Nevermind, I actually dont need the image, just draw the shapes into the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/):

> ZedGraph is a class library, user control, and web control for .net,
>   written in C#, for drawing 2D Line, Bar, and Pie Charts. It features
>   full, detailed customization capabilities, but most options have
>   defaults for ease of use.

I think that you would be re-inventing the wheel if you do it yourself. Also, requirements can change with time, so you might need to add some more items to your graph eventually.